# Intersection of uncountably many sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

The intersection of sigma algebras is a sigma algebra
$$
\bigcap_{\alpha\in \mathcal{A}} \mathcal{X}_\alpha 
$$
where $\mathcal{A}$ is an index set. However, in every definition I looked at (Billingsley, Cinlar, Evans, Bogachev, Wikipedia, Proof-Wiki) no one says if $\mathcal{A}$ is allowed to be **uncountable**, i.e. can it be *any* set?

Comment: Yes it can, any set. You can read through the proof that the resulting intersection is a sigma algebra and verify that no assumptions as to the size of the index set are used.

Comment: $\mathcal{A}$ can be any set, including uncountable sets. Moreover, if there is a need to exclude uncountable index sets, mathematical texts will typically say "countable intersection".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $\mathcal A$ can be an arbitrary index set. In particular, it is allowed to be uncountable. (This can be seen from inspecting the proof. Countability is never used.)

For a reference where it is explicitly mentioned that the index set can be arbitrary, see Theorem 1.15 of Achim Klenke's *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course* (Third Edition).